# how to call function from one component to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am working on 2 components, one is `Game` and second it `PickWinner`, Game is my parent component, from this component i want to call `PickWinner` component `pickWinner` function, from `Game` component `startPickWinnerCardTimer` function, can anyone please help me how to do that, here i have put my both component , any help will  be really appreciated.

Game.tsx

```
import {PickWinner} from "@Areas/Game/Components/Gameplay/PickWinner";

class Game extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<IGameParams>, IGameState>
{
    private supportDelayTimeout = 0;
    public interval;
    public interval_show_winner_counter;
    public can_we_update=0;
    public number_seconds=30;

    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<IGameParams>) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            socketData: SocketDataStore.state,
            gameData: GameDataStore.state,
            userData: UserDataStore.state,
            restartLoading: false,
            restartDelayed: true,
            showSupport: false,
            chatDrawerOpen: true,
            isFirstTime: false,
            total: this.number_seconds,
            showTimer: false,
            displayTimer : '00:30',
        };
    }

    public startPickWinnerCardTimer = (winnerGuid) => {
        this.interval_show_winner_counter = setInterval(function (winnerGuid) {
            let timer =  120, minutes, seconds;
            if(typeof timer!==undefined && timer!=null) {
                minutes = parseInt(timer/60 as any,10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer%60 as any,10);
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                
                console.log("show winner timer");
                console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds);

                this.setState({displayTimer:minutes + ":" + seconds})
                
                
                if (--timer < 0) {
                    pickWinner(winnerGuid);
                    this.setState({total:this.number_seconds,showTimer:false});
                    clearInterval(this.interval_show_winner_counter);
                    return false;
                } 
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private getWinnerFromState(state: IGameState) {
        const {
            players,
            settings
        } = state.gameData.game ?? {};

        const playerGuids = Object.keys(players ?? {});
        const roundsToWin = getTrueRoundsToWin(state.gameData.game as ClientGameItem);
        const winnerGuid = playerGuids.find(pg => (players?.[pg].wins ?? 0) >= roundsToWin);
        return winnerGuid;
    }
};

export default withRouter(Game);
```

PickWinner.tsx

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import * as React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import {useDataStore} from "../../../../Global/Utils/HookUtils";
import {GameDataStore} from "../../../../Global/DataStore/GameDataStore";
import {WhiteCard} from "../../../../UI/WhiteCard";
import {UserDataStore} from "../../../../Global/DataStore/UserDataStore";
import sanitize from "sanitize-html";
import {LoadingButton} from "../../../../UI/LoadingButton";
import {CardId} from "../../../../Global/Platform/Contract";
import {cardDefsLoaded} from "../../../../Global/Utils/GameUtils";

export interface IPickWinnerProps
{
    children?: undefined;
    canPick: boolean;
    timeToPick: boolean;
    revealMode: boolean;
    hasWinner: boolean;
    onPickWinner?: (winnerGuid: string) => Promise<any>;
}



export const PickWinner: React.FC<IPickWinnerProps> = (

    {
        onPickWinner,
        canPick,
        timeToPick,
        hasWinner,
        revealMode
    }

) =>
{

    let interval_show_winner_counter;
    this.props.func(this, 1234);

    const gameData = useDataStore(GameDataStore);
    const userData = useDataStore(UserDataStore);
    const [pickWinnerLoading, setPickWinnerLoading] = useState(false);
    const [updateShowWinnerTimer,setUpdateShowWinnerTimer] = useState('02:00');

    const me = gameData.game?.players?.[userData.playerGuid] ?? gameData.game?.spectators?.[userData.playerGuid];

    const defsLoaded = cardDefsLoaded(gameData);

    if (!me || !gameData.game || !defsLoaded)
    {
        return null;
    }

    const pickWinner = (winnerGuid: string) =>
    {
        if (onPickWinner)
        {
            setPickWinnerLoading(true);

            onPickWinner(winnerGuid)
                .finally(() => setPickWinnerLoading(false));
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: What actions did you perform? What part of manual do you referencing for? Share reproducible error example, please

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not the way to go about things in React. Usually what you want to do is pass down functionality to children in props, and pass up notifications from children in events.

you can use **forwardRef** for this issue. Try [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Also you want to pass any functionality or notification from child, you should use **Redux** to notify anything to parent component.